# how to find the number of possible pattern?

Tags: permutation

1.7 In Time Division Multiple Access (TDMA) communication, a time frame is
divided into ten time slots such that each time slot can be used by any user.
Suppose that a frame is received that contains three packets due to user 1, two
due to user 2, and the rest of the time slots were empty. How many frame
patterns are possible?

here we have 10 time slot to be fill  by using
3 packet from user-1
2 packet from user-2

the rest 5 frame slot will be empty ?
so what will be the total patterns

Comment: Please share more details. How is the given problem related to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be seen as a permutation problem. As there is 10 time slots, there are 10! possible combinations. But packets of same user can be considere identical. Moreover empty slots are identical too. so according to the rule of permutaion, the answer will be = This can be seen as a permutation problem. As there is 10 time slots, there are 10! possible combinations. But packets of same user can be considere identical. Moreover empty slots are identical too. so according to the rule of permutaion, the answer will be = 10! / (3!*2!*5!)